# ThreeJS: Material update during runtime

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I'm loading an OBJ object with material file (MTL) to a scene, which works great. The MTL file points to a JPG texture for the object, which I modify visually on runtime.

Now I would like to reload the object with the new material (modified JPG). I could remove and add the whole object to the scene, but this is not optimal in terms of performance.

Is there a way to just **re-render** the object with the new texture or **re-attache** the updated MTL?

```
mtlLoader.load("material.mtl", function (materials) {
materials.preload();
objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
objLoader.setPath("static/models/");
objLoader.load("object.obj", function (object) {
  scene.add(object);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reload the object once it's already in your scene. Just find the material, and [change its .map property](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=mesh#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial.map)

```js
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var newTexture = textureLoader.load('./path/to/new/image.png');
object.material.map = newTexture;
```

You can use the built-in [`TextureLoader` class](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/TextureLoader) to load new textures.

Comment: This works so far, but I run into an issue as this overwrites the whole texture. I have different models (OBJ & MTL) sharing the same JPG texture file in different ways. 

The material file and JPG stay the same, except the JPG will have visual changes.
Is there a way to just reload/refresh the material of an object?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, then. You can update the material of an object with `object.material.property = newValue`, or you can assign a new material with `object.material = new THREE.MeshXXXMaterial();` The type of material you choose is up to you, there's Basic, Standard, Phong, Toon, etc...

Comment: Let me simplify this a bit. I have an 3D obj model loaded with a material file and a jpg texture on my localhost website, that works. Now I'm adding a logo to the jpg texture ie. in Photoshop and save it under the same file. How can I now update the model and see the updated jpg texture?

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback. Quick question, which might solve my problem. 

How can I apply a material (MTL) to an object afterwards, i.e. after it has been already loaded into the scene?